# please tell me the difference between these two codes

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, async-await

i think both of them are giving me same promise but later one doesn't work as promise. it gives me "TypeError: data.then is not a function"

```
 try{
    await docClient.get(params).promise().then(x => console.log(x));//this one works
     const data = await docClient.get(params).promise();
     data.then(x =>console.log(x));//this.doesen't 

    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
```

Function Logs:
START RequestId: 914e5709-7cf2-4978-9b58-d338ebee52dc Version: $LATEST
2019-11-08T04:39:22.259Z    914e5709-7cf2-4978-9b58-d338ebee52dc

INFO    "Event: event"

2019-11-08T04:39:22.437Z    914e5709-7cf2-4978-9b58-d338ebee52dc

INFO    { Item: { firstname: 'Bob', id: '12345', lastname: 'Johnson' } }

2019-11-08T04:39:22.487Z    914e5709-7cf2-4978-9b58-d338ebee52dc

INFO    TypeError: data.then is not a function

at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index2.js:21:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

Comment: Can you try: const data = docClient.get(params).promise();
     await data.then(x =>console.log(x));

Comment: that didn't work , giving me same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
await docClient.get(params).promise().then(x => console.log(x));
```

Means that *the entire* expression `docClient.get(params).promise().then(x => console.log(x))` returns a Promise and you `await` until it's resolved.

```js
await docClient.get(params).promise()
```

Means you get a promise out of this part of the expression *and `await` it* thus unwrapping it into a plain value, which means that `data` is not a Promise any more and thus `data.then(x =>console.log(x))` fails.

If you want to preserve the Promise in the second case, then you can not `await` it:

```js
const data = docClient.get(params).promise();
await data.then(x =>console.log(x));
```

Although this is probably not very good, since you're better off using either `await` or Promises instead of breaking the chained Promise API to `await` part of it. You can just drop the Promises API altogether

```js
const data = await docClient.get(params).promise();
console.log(data);
```

Worth noting that you can use use the alternative syntax with a callback but Promise or `await` are probably better:

```js
const data = docClient.get(params, function(err, data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your first statement:

```
docClient.get(params).promise()
```

is a promise, so of course, you can add a `.then()` handler to it like:

```
docClient.get(params).promise().then(...)
```

Putting an `await` in front of it:

```
await docClient.get(params).promise().then(...)
```

doesn't affect the `.then()` itself, that's still a method call on `docClient.get(params).promise()`.  It just awaits the result of the `.then()`.  If you need some extra parens to see the order of evaluation, it would be like this:

```
await ( docClient.get(params).promise().then(...) )
```

though the extra parens are not needed in execution.

---

In your second statement:

```
 const data = await docClient.get(params).promise();
```

Because of the `await`, the variable `data` contains the resolved value of the promise.  It's not a promise.  So, when you attempt:

```
 data.then()
```

there's no `.then()` method on the value in the `data` variable so it's an error.

Answer (score 0):

Like it says in the error, `data.then` is not a function. Since you `await`ed the promise the value is scalar at that point and you would need to `console.log(data)` to see it.